# NetSuite Script AWS SP API STS request

Tags: amazon-web-services, netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to connect to Amazon SP API through NetSuite scripts but unable to establish the connection, i am able to get the access token but when i try to create the authorization i keep getting the error that signature does not match. Need help to get the STS connection setup.

Below is part of the STS request that i am trying.

```
const amzDate = getAmzDate();
        const datestamp = amzDate.split("T")[0];
        var host = "sts.amazonaws.com";
        //https://sts.amazonaws.com/?Version=2011-06-15&Action=AssumeRole&RoleSessionName=Test&RoleArn=myactualARN&DurationSeconds=3600
        const canonicalUri = '/';
        const canonicalQuerystring = "?Version=2011-06-15&Action=AssumeRole&RoleSessionName=Test&RoleArn=mayactualARNe&DurationSeconds=3600";
        const canonicalHeaders = 'host:' + host + '\n' + 'x-amz-date:' + amzDate + '\n';
        const signedHeaders = 'host';
        const payloadHash = crypto.createHash({ algorithm: crypto.HashAlg.SHA256 });
        const canonicalRequest = 'GET\n' +canonicalUri + '\n' +canonicalQuerystring + '\n' +canonicalHeaders + '\n' +signedHeaders + '\n' +payloadHash.digest().toLowerCase();
        log.debug("canonicalRequest",canonicalRequest);
        const credentialScope = datestamp + '/' + REGION + '/' + SERVICE_NAME_STS + '/' + 'aws4_request';
        const canonicalHash = crypto.createHash({ algorithm: crypto.HashAlg.SHA256 });
        canonicalHash.update({ input: canonicalRequest });
        const stringToSign = ALGORITHM + '\n' +amzDate + '\n' +credentialScope + '\n' +canonicalHash.digest().toLowerCase();
        log.debug("stringToSign",stringToSign);
        const signingKey = getSignatureKey(amamzonConnectionKeysArray.secretkey, datestamp, REGION, SERVICE_NAME_STS);
        const signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(stringToSign, signingKey);
        const authorizationHeader = ALGORITHM + ' ' + 'Credential=' + amamzonConnectionKeysArray.accesskey + '/' + credentialScope + ', ' + 'SignedHeaders=' + signedHeaders + ', ' + 'Signature=' + signature;
        log.debug("authorizationHeader",authorizationHeader);
        log.debug("Credentials",amamzonConnectionKeysArray.accesskey + '/' + credentialScope);
        const stsResponse = https.get({
            url: amamzonConnectionKeysArray.urlsts,
            headers: {
                'host': host,
                'x-amz-date': amzDate,
                'Authorization': authorizationHeader
            },
        });
```